# XslTransform to XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xslt

Currently I have this code which works fine but I want to migrate to XslCompiledTransform. When this code was written the evidence was required or it would not work. Does anybody know if this is still required in the XslCompiledTransform.

```
XslTransform transformer = new XslTransform();
transformer.Load( navigator, new XmlUrlResolver(), this.GetType().Assembly.Evidence);
```

Here is my suggested code to change to.

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load( navigator,new XsltSettings(), new XmlUrlResolver() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `new XsltSettings()` then you are using default settings with both script and the document function being disabled. That would be equivalent to using

```
XslTransform transformer = new XslTransform();
transformer.Load( navigator, new XmlUrlResolver(), null);
```

Comment: So if i used new XsltSettings(true,true) that would be the same as my current code ?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct translation of the `Evidence` based security model with `XslTransform` and the `XsltSettings` based one with `XslCompiledTransform`. I am afraid I don't remember the details as to what `XslTransform` does, the docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50ste364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx suggests that `xslt.Load(xslNav, resolver, this.GetType().Assembly.Evidence);` is done to trust the stylesheet, I would need to test whether that results in permission to use scripts in all cases but I don't have time to do that. Maybe someone else can help or you can test yourself

Comment: i'll test it myself it was only if you knew off the top of your head thanks for your help